# How to install tor browser in Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, tor

How to install Tor Browser in Kali linux?

Is it possible to install Tor Browser using the package manager in the same way as Debian 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the installation instructions to Kali Docs:

[Installing Tor Browser on Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/tools/tor/)

Kali Linux provide the `torbrowser-launcher` tool to install Tor Browser.

**Install instructions**

Open the terminal then run the following commands:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt install tor torbrowser-launcher
```

As user run the following command:

```
kali@kali:~$ torbrowser-launcher
```

First time it will download and install Tor Browser including the signature verification.

Next time it will be used to update and launch Tor Browser.

**Reference**

[Debian Wiki: TorBrowser](https://wiki.debian.org/TorBrowser)

Author: gad3r